# Can't get axios to perform get without full url

Tags: javascript, express, routes, axios, mern

Every time I try to use /bikes or /bikes/add in my axios requests, it never seems to connect. I always get something like this:

**xhr.js:178 GET http://localhost:3000/bikes/ 404 (Not Found)**

However, when I use the full url, like: `http://localhost:4000/bikes/` it connects perfectly. I tried messing with the app.get in server.js, the get in my route file, and the actually axios.get in my bikes-list file to no avail.

Anyone have any ideas? This is part of a MERN app.

bikes-list.js(component) snippet:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/bikes/')
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({bikes: response.data});
        })
        .catch(function (error){
            console.log(error);
        })
}
```

server.js snippet:

```
app.use('/bikes', bikeRoutes);
```

bikes.js(route) snippet:

```
router.get('/',function(req, res) {
Bikes.find(function(err, bikes) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        res.json(bikes);
    }
}); });
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's serving on 3000? Does it have a proxy to 4000?

Comment: How is it supposed to know you want to make the request to a different server (running on port 4000) instead of the server the HTML document came from (on port 3000) unless you tell it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe the cause is that you are not using the right port when using `/bikes`? One solution is to create a small module like this:

```
// client.js

var axios = require('axios');

var axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:4000',
    /* other custom settings */
});

module.exports = axiosInstance;
```

and then use this new module in your code instead of requiring axios
directly:

```
var client = require('./client');

client.get('relative/path')
```